# vuejs use fetch Api get data of projects.json: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, fetch

I am practicing **fetch Api**, and trying to get the data of **projects.json** file in my vue-cli project and to show it on **console**.

**Project architecture:**

```
src/views/Projects.vue
src/assets/projects.json
```

**Projects.vue** in created method we fetch the json data

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello WOrld</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "projects",
  created() {
    fetch("../assets/projects.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

when load the component **Syntax Error** is shown.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

**projects.json** contains just the basics

```
    {
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "pie station"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "automate dryer"
    }
  ],
  "profile": {
    "name": "someaone"
  }
}
```

How can I show in console the content of my .json file using fetch Api?

Comment: It's not returning JSON, remove the `.then(res => res.json())` to see what it is actually returning.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the network tab in the console, you'll probably notice that your fetch call is returning a 404 html page. The server is most likely not serving the package.json but that depends on your setup. (you normally wouldn't want to serve it anyway)

Are you running a default vue cli environment with an `npm run serve`? If so you can add a json file in the assets dir, this should be served normally and it can be fetched at /assets/{insert the rest of the path here}.

**EDIT**

Say you have projects.json in the assets dir like you mentioned in the comments you should be able to access it with `fetch("/assets/projects.json")`

Comment: right it should be into the assets dir.
To do that I would probably use a symbolic link.

Comment: maybe I should have not used package.json as example, but originaly I use "assets/projects.json" and same error occured

Comment: And what do you get when visiting the url directly? something like `localhost:3000/assets/projects.json`?

Comment: @Vanz Added to my answer according to your comment

Comment: @red-X when I visit localhost:8080/assets/projects.json nothing is showing